# Mysql code runs but the foreign key values are not showing in table in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

My code runs in phpmyadmin but the foreign key values are not showing in table and when I update it the message shows "0 rows affected"

my table schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE fee_report (
fr_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
school_id INT NOT NULL,
branch_id INT NOT NULL,
student_id INT NOT NULL,
ledger VARCHAR(55),
bill_no VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
fdate date NOT NULL,
receipt_no VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
dr float NOT NULL,
cr float NOT NULL,
balance float NOT NULL,
particulars VARCHAR(155),
updated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_frschool FOREIGN KEY (school_id)
REFERENCES school(school_id),
CONSTRAINT fk_frbranch FOREIGN KEY (branch_id)
REFERENCES branch(branch_id),
CONSTRAINT fk_frstudent FOREIGN KEY (student_id)
REFERENCES student(student_id)
) ENGINE = INNODB;


INSERT INTO fee_report(school_id,branch_id,student_id,ledger,bill_no,fdate,dr,balance,particulars,feetype) 
VALUES(1,1,13,'TGS007','SESNOV1020',CURDATE(),'2850','-14450','11','Tuition Fee,Transport Fee,Smart Class Fee,SA-1 Exam Fee')
```

Why foreign keys school_id, branch_id and student_id are not showing in table
and when I remove foreign key constraint the values are visible in table

Comment: What do you see and what do you expect to see?

Comment: I saw all the data were inserted in the table but the schhol_id, branch_id and student_id was not visible in the table

Comment: could you please post the data you see and the data you expected to see?

Comment: @Shaun if you could post the other tables as well we can actuall rebuild the situation and easily find a solution.

Comment: @Jester the thing is this code WAS WORKING EARLIER But after continuous insertion of data this issue occured.Please help me why this issue occured as the foreign key values are present in the table

Comment: It's hard to help if you don't provide more information, can you make an sql export of your database and put it into sql fiddle, give us a link. http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ef28/1